# How to implement service class in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I am trying to learn the OOP and DI. I am receiving help from FOSUserBundle and coding my own bundle to learn things.

FOS has:

`UserManager.php` and `UserManagerInterface.php`.

Now, I want to make UserService.php in the `Service` folder.

I am confused about whether I can replace `UserManager.php` with `userService.php`, or do I need to make a new file?

`userService.php` extends `userManager.php`.

I want to keep things modular.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to edit any file in FOSUserBundle, go with the second solution : inheritance, and use the configuration file to select your userManager instead of the FOS user manager.